# Re-subscribing in Meteor reloads all items

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe, infinite-scroll

I have this code:

```
Template.messageList.onCreated(function onCreated() {
    this.state = new ReactiveDict();
    this.state.setDefault({
        limit: 5
    });

    this.autorun(() => {
        this.subscribe('messages', {limit: this.state.get('limit')});
    });

});

Template.messageList.helpers({

    messages () {
        const instance = Template.instance();
        return Messages.find({}, MessagesFilter.common({limit: instance.state.get('limit')}));
    }

});

Template.messageList.events({
    'click .ui.button.more' (event, instance) {
        const limit = instance.state.get('limit');
        instance.state.set('limit', limit + 5);
    }
});
```

It's intended to be a infinite scroll, but it presents weird events. Right now, the elements on page are reloaded when the `limit` changes.

Looks like meteor is re-subscribing (which is expected by the documentation) but this is reloading all the documents, it deletes the messages and then reload the with the new `limit` value.

How can I prevent it? I want a infinite scroll, but the way it behaves right now looks impossible.

Here's a video of what's happening.
http://recordit.co/mlsGThOdHp

Here's the repository:
https://github.com/Sornii/sayito/tree/infinite-scroll

Comment: What does `MessagesFilter.common(...)` do?

Comment: It only wraps a custom filter, it's like a helper, I'll edit to add the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
this.autorun(() => {
    this.subscribe('messages', {limit: this.state.get('limit')});
});
```

To

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
    this.subscribe('messages', {limit: this.state.get('limit')});
});
```

And now it works the way I want to.